# popup window close by the same button

Tags: android

I wanna close the popup button by the same button But when I click on the button again, it reopen the window instead of closing it, and also should close the window when i click outside of the window any where, can anyone help me?

here is my code,

```
ivmainmenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @SuppressWarnings("null")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             if(isShowing)
                {
                     PopupWindow popupWindow = null;
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                     isShowing=false;
                }
                else
                {
                 isShowing=true;
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
                    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupwindow, null);  
                  final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
                        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(ivmainmenu, 0,14);
                        popupView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);    
                        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
                        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

                    TextView tvpopupwork = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvpopupwork);
                    TextView tvpopupabout = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvpopupabout);
                    TextView tvpopupservices = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvpopupservices);
                    TextView tvpopupcontact = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvpopupcontact);


                    Typeface typeFace2 =  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/arboriaboldregular.ttf");
                    tvpopupwork.setTypeface(typeFace2);
                    tvpopupabout.setTypeface(typeFace2);
                    tvpopupservices.setTypeface(typeFace2);
                    tvpopupcontact.setTypeface(typeFace2);


                    tvpopupwork.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Ourwork.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    tvpopupabout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Aboutus.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                            startActivity(intent);  
                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    tvpopupservices.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Services.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    tvpopupcontact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Contact.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                }
         }
            });
```

I have tried this code but I am getting error when i click that button again,
This is logcat, please help me out to solve  this error.

[image]

Please help me in this I am not getting any solution,
thank you.

Comment: use count ..,if count=0 then open window..,if count=1 then close window

Comment: can u please edit the code i am new to this?

Comment: on which button you want to..,do this???

Comment: ivmainmenu(menu button)...

Comment: when i click on menu once it should be open and it should be close from the same button...

Comment: akky ..,the solution which has given you..,are correct ..,try them

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49052/discussion-between-akky777-and-rajshree)

Comment: At which line you got NPE?

Comment: This has been answered here. Marking this duplicate


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267224/popupwindow-closing-issue-by-same-button/27561929#27561929

Answer (score 0):

Make a boolean flag like showDialog.
showDialog=false first time

```
if(!showDialog){
display popup
showDialog=true
}else{
popup.dismiss();
showDialog=false;
}
```

Comment: what red line did you refere?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the variable `isShowing` a global static variable and put it outside the `onClickListener` because in your code, each time you click on the `View` it re-initialized again with the value `false` so you will never do the required behaviour

```
public class ClassName .....{

                 boolean isShowing = false;
                 ...
                 ...
                 ...
                 ivmainmenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(isShowing)
        {
             PopupWindow popupWindow = null;
            popupWindow.dismiss();
             isShowing=false;
        }
        else
        {
         isShowing=true;
                 ...
                 ...
                 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

//Add isShowing=true; statement in your else part code

ivmainmenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        boolean isShowing = false;
        if(isShowing)
        {
             PopupWindow popupWindow = null;
            popupWindow.dismiss();
             isShowing=false;
        }
        else
        {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupwindow, null);  
          final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(ivmainmenu, 0,14);
                popupView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);    
                popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
                popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

                isShowing=true; //This statement will solve your problem.

            TextView tvpopupwork = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvpopupwork);
            TextView tvpopupabout = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvpopupabout);
            TextView tvpopupservices = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvpopupservices);
            TextView tvpopupcontact = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvpopupcontact);

            Typeface typeFace2 =  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/arboriaboldregular.ttf");
            tvpopupwork.setTypeface(typeFace2);
            tvpopupabout.setTypeface(typeFace2);
            tvpopupservices.setTypeface(typeFace2);
            tvpopupcontact.setTypeface(typeFace2);


            tvpopupwork.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Ourwork.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });

            tvpopupabout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Aboutus.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(intent);  
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });

            tvpopupservices.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Services.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });

            tvpopupcontact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Contact.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }

       });;

        }
    }
    });
```